# How to declare a (multi-dimensional) array with value inputted by the user?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

What we're being taught at school is this:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
int array[x];
```

OR

```
int x, y;
cin >> x >> y;
int array[x][y];
```

However, I am aware that it's invalid code in C++. But even if it is, it still does the job and works as expected, however, I'm looking to find the answer of how it's properly done?

Comment: Search the web or StackOverflow for "C++ matrix implementation".  The C++ FAQ has a good discussion on overloading operators for accessing a matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not standard C++ but many compiler including [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) support [variable length arrays](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FVariable-length_array&ei=f_ScUouxDsyGkQexmoD4AQ&usg=AFQjCNFlYxoCSighxgS6Ygnu_mwDjSdecg&bvm=bv.57155469,d.eW0) as an extension in *C++* even though it is a *C99* feature. Althought both `gcc` and `clang` will warn you this is an extension if the `-pedantic` flag is used with a message similar to this:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘array’ [-Wvla]

An alternative in standard C++ would be to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or dynamic allocation via *new*:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
int *array new int[x] ;
//...
delete [] array ;
```

the *2D* dynamic allocation case is well covered in [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new). Using a container is probably better since you do not have to worry about *deleting* the allocated memory afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Properly it is done with dynamic arrays:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
int* array = new int[x];
```

Note, that in this case it is your responsibility to free the allocated memory; or use smart pointers.

Another approach is using STL containers, e.g. `vector`.

Comment: I would go for `int *const array` ;)

Comment: Don't forget `delete`, and exception-safety precautions, if you really want to muck around with low-level pointer juggling.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I thought it was obvious, but I extended my answer, thanks for the note.

Comment: @user2485710: Please explain why it is better to use a constant pointer in a general situation?

Comment: @CMate because const-correctness is a really good philosophy and you should stick with it whenever it's possible in C++. It will also help you in debugging your application, because if you try to modify `array` you will get an error, this way you are sure that `array` will always point where you think it's pointing, anywhere in the code.

Comment: @user2485710 I see your point and its advantages, but what if I would like to `delete` the array and point the variable to a new array? Or, with this concept I shouldn't do that, and rather initialize a new variable instead? That could be messy sometimes.

Comment: @CMate in that case you probably should switch to "real" C++ containers, it will be messy anyway with raw pointers and arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is done either by using standard container std::vector or by allocating the array dynamically in the heap. For example

```
int x, y;
cin >> x >> y;
int **array = new int * [x];

for ( size_t i = 0; i < x; i++ ) array[i] = new int[y];
```

Comment: It would be better to use int i = 0 in the loop instead of size_t i = 0 because x is declared as int. I simply did not take into account that x is defined as int.:)

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to get a dynamically sized array is with `std::vector`:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
vector<int> array(x);
```

Multidimensional arrays are a bit more complicated; one option is:

```
int x, y;
cin >> x >> y;
vector<vector<int>> array(x, vector<int>(y));
```

More efficiently, but less simply, you might consider using a one-dimensional array of size `x*y`, with accessor functions to treat is as two-dimensional.